# what crusader skills benefit from health globe bonus affix?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

I heard that some skills (Wrathfull passive for example) benefit from the Health Globe Healing Bonus affix.

How can I know which skills benefit from that stat? Is there any rule?

Comment: if it benefits from the globe affix it'll usualy say in the skill description, something along the lines of: "adds 1% of your health globe bonus"

Comment: so wrathfull is the only one then

Comment: if its the only one, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As of [patch 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/patch-205-now-live-5-13-2014). The only ability that benefits directly from "Health Globe Healing Bonus" is [Wrathful](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/passive/wrathful).

> How can I know which skills benefit from that stat?

The skill will tell you, just like [Wrathful](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/passive/wrathful) does.

> Is there any rule?

Not sure i understand this question. lol